# For how long will a query wait, and what will it do post the wait when offline index rebuild is running?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, index-tuning

When an offline index rebuild is running, and a CRUD query is fired, assuming the rebuild takes couple of hours.

1. How long will the query wait for rebuild to complete?
2. What will it do once it finishes waiting, assuming that rebuild is still running?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer to your questions:

1. Forever
2. See above (this doesn't happen, because of above)

But there are exceptions:

The client app can have defined a timeout less then indefinite, meaning it will send an "abort" (formally called "attention") on the TDS protocol after that many seconds. SQL Server receives the attention signal and aborts the query. If it is a modification query it will be rolled back, but if you have an explicit transaction, then that transaction will not be rolled back. Note that it was the *client* that aborted, not the database engine.

The session can have specified SET LOCK_TIMEOUT to a higher value than 0, meaning after waiting so long for a lock, you get error 1222. Again, just like above, the DML command will be rolled back but not the surrounding transaction.

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` will cause rollback after attention or lock timeout